# Comparing 2 HashMap with Key as String and Value as UserDefined Object

Tags: java

I want to output a boolean as true indicating both maps have same Key and values.
If i use equals() it returns false.
How can i output as true , Object references are different. But the entries are same
I have 2 maps below

```
Map<String,Information> map1=new HashMap<>();
map1.put("key1", new Information("10","20","30","40"));
map1.put("key2", new Information("11","22","33","44"));
Map<String,Information> map2=new HashMap<>();
map2.put("key1", new Information("10","20","30","40"));
map2.put("key2", new Information("11","22","33","44"));
```

POJO as below : with public getters and setters

```
public class Information {

private String value1;
    private String value2;
    private String value3;
    private String value4;

public Information(String value1,
                      String value2,
                      String value3,
                      String value4)
{
   this.value1 = value1;
   this.value2 = value2;
   this.value3 = value3;
   this.value4 = value4;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `HashMap` uses `equals()` to compare two entries. For `HashMap<String, Information>`, it uses `equals()` of `String` and `Information` to decide if two entries are equal. Since your `Information` class does not override `equals()` from `Object`, the equality comparison is based on addresses.

To compare two `Information` by value, you can override `equals()` inside `Information` class:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (obj == this) return true;
    if (obj instanceof Information info) {
        return value1.equals(info.value1) &&
               value2.equals(info.value2) &&
               value3.equals(info.value3) &&
               value4.equals(info.value4);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: if (obj instanceof Information info) shows error - The Java feature 'Pattern Matching in instanceof Expressions' is only available with source level 16 and above. Am using java 1.8

Comment: Type casting the object worked in the traditional way

Comment: Don't forget to override `hashcode` when you override equals https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446763/difference-between-equals-and-hashcode#:~:text=The%20value%20returned%20by%20hashCode,the%20reverse%20is%20not%20true.

Answer (score 1):

You have to feed the same objects like this

```
    Information info1 = new Information("10", "20", "30", "40");
    Information info2 = new Information("11", "22", "33", "44");
    Map<String, Information> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("key1", info1);
    map1.put("key2", info2);
    Map<String, Information> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("key1", info1);
    map2.put("key2", info2);

    System.out.println(map2.equals(map1));// prints true
```

You are getting **false** cause you are comparing two different instances of **Information** classs.

Comment: You are welcome! Please let me know if you need sth else!

Comment: What if map2 has info3 and info4 ....but still it same as info1 and info2...Comparing map with different instances

Comment: Well, if `info3` refers to `info1` and `info4` refers to `info2` I think it should print `true` too.

Comment: info3 and info4 does not refer to info1 and info 2 , they are separate objects...equals() way will not work in that case ,, any alternate method to compare map values in this scenarios ?

Comment: @Simon Smith answered this to us. Thank him!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245063/discussion-between-mohamad-ghaith-alzin-and-user2918673).